# A man spends 80% of his income. If his income is increased by 40% and expenditure is increased by 10%, by what percentage is savings increased?

Tags: percentages

Actual Answer is $160\%$.

What I have done: 
I took his income as $100$.  According to the question, his income is increased by $40$ so, $140$.

According to the question, his expenditure is $80$, then his expenditure increased by $10\%$ so $90\%$.

According to the question, the man's saving is $20$ because $100-80 = 20$, After his expenditure increased by $10\%$ his new saving is $50$, i.e $140 - 90 = 50$.

I want to find the percentage of saving is increased, so from saving difference $50 - 20$ is $30$.

$30/20  \times 100 = 150\%$.  I got $150\%$, but the answer is $160\%$.

Comment: 10% of increase on 80 is _not_ 90. It is 88.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, An income $I$ is sum of Expenditure/Spending $E$ and Saving $S$.

So,

$I=E+S$

Let's assume that, 
His income is \$100.

Then, $\text E=\$80$, and $\text S=\$20$.

Now, If income is increasing by $40%$, then

$I=I+0.40I=1.40I=1.40*100=140$

And you are also increasing E by 10, 
then

$E=1.10E=1.10*80=88$

So,

$S=140-88=52$.

Now, %age increase in saving

$$={\frac{(52-20)}{20}}*100=32/20*100=160$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : His initial expenditure is $80$. It is increased by $10 \%$, so it becomes $\frac{110}{100}.80 = 88$ and not $90$.

So his new saving is $52$, which you can check yields the correct answer.

Comment: You meant increased by $10\%$.

Answer (score 0):

Let income be 100
Expenditure is  80
Saving is 20
New salary 140 i.e 40% of 100+100
New expenditure 80*10/100=8
i.e 80+8=88
New saving =140-88=52
Difference in saving=52-20=32
% of increase in saving =32/20*100=160%